# Trying to make a new table by pulling data from two tables and keep getting 'Error: Every derived table must have its own alias' on this query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, subquery

I have an 'Orders' table and a 'Records' table.

Orders table has the following columns:

```
order_id       order_date        seller        order_price
```

Records table has the following columns:

```
order_id        record_created_at         record_log
```

I'm trying to pull and compile the following list of data but I keep getting an error message:

```
order_week
seller
total_num_orders
under100_count --this is the number of orders that were < $100
over100_count --this is the number of order that >= $100
approved --this is the number of orders that were approved by the payment platform
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT order_week, seller, total_num_orders, under100_count, over100_count, approved
FROM (

    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(WEEK FROM order_created_at) AS order_week,
        merchant_name AS seller, 
        COUNT(merchant_name) AS total_num_orders,
        SUM(DISTINCT total_order_price < 100) AS under100_count,
        SUM(DISTINCT total_order_price >= 100) AS over100_count
    FROM orders o
    GROUP BY order_week, seller)

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) AS approved
    FROM records r
    WHERE record_log = 'order approved'
    GROUP BY order_id)

ON l.order_id = o.order_id;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your subqueries are not returning the join key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do I resolve that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: desired results are the ones as I've listed: order_week, seller, total_num_orders, under100_count --this is the number of orders that were < $100, over100_count --this is the number of order that >= $100, approved

Comment: Column headers are not sample data.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery in the `join` needs an alias. It also needs to return the `order_id` column, so it can be joined.

```
inner join ( select order_id, ... from records ... group by order_id) r  --> here
on l.order_id = o.order_id
```

I would actually write your query as:

```
select 
    extract(week from o.order_created_at) as order_week,
    o.merchant_name as seller, 
    count(*) as total_num_orders,
    sum(o.total_order_price < 100) as under100_count,
    sum(o.total_order_price >= 100) as over100_count,
    sum(r.approved) approved
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, count(*) approved
    from records r
    where record_log = 'order approved'
    group by order_id
) r on r.order_id = o.order_id;
group by order_week, seller, approved
```

Rationale:

- you don't want, and need, `distinct` in the aggregate functions here; it is inefficient, and might even yield wrong results
- `count(*)` is more efficient `count(<expression>)` - so, use it, unless you know why you are doing otherwise
- I removed an unecessary level of nesting

If there are orders without records, you might want a `left join` instead.

Comment: @GandalfTheWat: I re-read my answer: the subquery solution is not valid standardSQL (although MySQL might accept it), I removed it. I also slightly changed the first query.

Comment: how would I get the proportion of approved orders out of total orders? I would imagine something like COUNT(raw_log = 'order approved')/COUNT(*)